# How can I show the content in listView by "pushing" in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, stack, android-listfragment

I am a new Android developer.

In iOS, there is a class called `UINavigationController` by which I can push a new viewController to stack and go back to the previous view by pushing the "back" button.

```
[self pushViewController: myViewController animated:YES]
```

As far as I know, the instance of `UINavigationController` has a property to hold the controllers. Therefore, all the attributes in each of the controllers are saved as well in the stack.

I am wondering if the Android can do something similar.
Now I have two fragments to simulate the *split view* as iOS.
I subclass `ListFragment` to represent the `lsit view* in the left side and the other fragment to represent the *item detail* in the right side.

When user taps one of the items in the list view it will go to another list.

```
        SecondFragment newFragment = new SecondFragment();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        getActionBar().setTitle("new items");

        transaction.commit();

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

However, I want to go back to the previous view by clicking the back button.
I realize that I should add the code as follow:

```
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

However, my application exits after I tap the back button.

If I want to go back, I have to make another `Fragment` transaction. The problem is, I want to save the content as item list in the `ListFragment` other than saving it to the `MainActivity`. It is much easier for me to retrieve the previous list view content from stack.

Is there any way in Android can do something similar in iOS as `UINavigationController`?